# My command which is being produced by my C# code isn't working in C#, but works perfectly when I paste it to cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

It's all about a line I want to use to get windows update information, which is part of wmic.

My code looks like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
string arguments = "qfe list full /format:htable > "+ path;
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("wmic", arguments);

procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
p.Start();
```

while path is the valid location where the file would be dumped, ending with a hotfixlog.htm of course.

The problem is, that nothing happens at all. However, when I take the final product from the arguments-variable, and paste it manually into cmd with 'wmic < variablecontent >' it's working perfectly fine and I end up with the .htm I expect.

The line created looks like this:

"qfe list full /format:htable > C:\Users\...\WindowsHotfixes.htm"

What do I have to change to make it work from the code? I was expecting the backslashes to cause problems, but when manually entering the line they don't.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't contain the part where you're actually retrieving something from that process; where are you redirecting the output to?

Comment: My bad, that line was some legacy line which I didn't clean up yet. There is no redirection happening

Comment: try `procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`

Comment: are you sure you are escaping the backslashes within your `path` string? can you show where you define `path`?

Comment: @user1666620 yes, they are escaped, I just noticed stackoverflow formatting uses that as well and makes 2 backslashes into one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will not work because the redirection operator (`>`) is not an element of the OS available to any application, but an operator in `cmd.exe`. It works in the command line because `cmd` is handling it, but `wmic` doesn't know what to do with it.

You can use the redirection if your command line is something like

```
cmd /c"wmic qfe list full /format:htable > x:\somewhere\file.htm"
```

Or you can remove the redirection and indicate to `wmic` that you want the data saved in a file

```
wmic /output:"x:\somewhere\file.htm" qfe list full /format:htable
```

Comment: Great, the second one works fine. I was already suspecting the > but I honestly didn't know what to replace it with.